# SQL COALESCE with multiple CASE conditions not returning correct data with IS NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have four tables `AG_AGENTS, Px_PAXWEB, vw_POSTCODE, vwPXPaxWeb` and the fields are `AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC, Px_Paxweb.COUNTRY, vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA, vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE`.

My query is returning all correct values except

1. `When AG_AGENTS ='Dom. -NAT', if Px_PaxWeb.COUNTRY  <> 'AUT' then vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA ( returning correct value till here) if vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA IS NULL Then AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC`
2. `When AG_AGENTS ='Dom. -NAT', if Px_PaxWeb.COUNTRY ='AUT' Then vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE( returning correct value till here) if vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE IS NULL Then AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC`

Basically not returning `AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC when vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE IS NULL and not returning AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC when vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA IS NULL`

My SQL query is as below

```
CASE WHEN AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC = 'Dom. - NAT' 
THEN (
    CASE WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY = 'AUT' THEN vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE
         WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY <> 'AUT' THEN vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA
         ELSE COALESCE (vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE,vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA,AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC) END
)
ELSE 
(
    CASE WHEN AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC = 'Int. – Inbound' Then vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA
         ELSE COALESCE( vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA,AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC) END
)
END AS SALES_AREA_DESC_2
```

Comment: Format your code properly and specify what RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...). SQL is merely a query language

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: For those who want better view http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24816283/2

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow your description. Both seem to be solved with an ISNULL (shown below). But you say this doesn't work?

```
CASE WHEN AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC = 'Dom. - NAT' 
     THEN CASE
          WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY = 'AUT' 
          THEN ISNULL(vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE, AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC) --#2 fix
          WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY <> 'AUT' 
          THEN ISNULL(vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA,AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC) --#1 fix
          ELSE COALESCE (vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE,vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA,AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC)
          END
     ELSE CASE
          WHEN AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC = 'Int. – Inbound'
          THEN vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA
          ELSE COALESCE(vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA,AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC) 
          END
     END AS SALES_AREA_DESC_2
```

Comment: @user2380064: Perhaps you are not aware yet but you can [accept an answer formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") if it has actually helped you out. Please consider also going through [your past questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2380064/user2380064?tab=questions) to see if you can accept answers to those too. You don't really have to, it's just that doing this helps future visitors to find solutions on this site more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CASE AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC
    WHEN 'Dom. - NAT' THEN
    (
        COALESCE(CASE 
                    WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY = 'AUT' THEN vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE
                    WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY <> 'AUT' THEN vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA END,
                 AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC)
    )
    WHEN 'Int. – Inbound' THEN vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA
    ELSE COALESCE(vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA,AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC)
END AS SALES_AREA_DESC_2
```